# Javascript use Variable in name

Tags: javascript, variables, eval

```
function test(art) {

        document.formular.eval(art+"_name").value =  "Test";
}
```

This gives an `eval is not a function error`.

I tried `document.formular.[art+'_name'].value =  "Test";`
Which won't work either.

Comment: check `formular` documentation for `eval` method. It looks like there is no such function in this object. You're probably confusing it with javascript's native `eval()`

Comment: If at all, it would be `eval('document.formular.'+art+'_name.value = "Test"')`, but [that's an incredibly bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
document.formular[art+'_name'].value =  "Test";
```